# Creating API calls in adobe air application

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have just started with Adobe Air applications. I did some hello worlds and AIR seems to be COOL for desktop applications . My next target is to connect to my adobe air desktop application through api.

I want to start a restful service here in adobe air application through which I will be guiding AIR app on what to do. 
How can we achieve this ? Was going through socket connections but there multithreading  seems to be a problem. ServerSocket at adobe air app would be able to handle multiple requests ?

Is there any option I can attach my java webapp into adobe air app and they can interact ?

Please help me out.

**EDIT :**

I searched over the web and found something like
 http://blog.brightworks.com/2008/03/26/a-simple-air-blazeds-remoting-example/

Just talking like a novice , Would it be good to have activemq running and I (webapp) publish message to activemq and my flex client being consumer receiving message for appropriate topic and then does operations as I want ?
 Would that be good ?
 I got something here 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-apache-nms.html

Please update!

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this.  One option is to use `ServerSocket` as you've said.  Another option is to simply embed your Java web app in the AIR package.  There's a [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2009/12/embedding-tomcat-and-blazeds-in-an-air-2-0-application/) that covers doing this with Tomcat in detail, but the basic principle is simple.

1. Embed your native Windows/OSX/Linux app in your AIR project.
2. Add some code to your installer function to copy the executable (e.g. Tomcat + webapp) to the applicationStorage directory.
3. When your AIR app runs, it can communicate via HTTP or custom sockets with your web app.

Comment: Thanks! I am going over the tutorial . If I am understanding correctly, the example to have tomcat webapp communicate to flex application and order it to do operations . In my first work, I want to invoke two cameras from two separate requests . I will finish homework and see if it can help me then will mark this good answer accepted :D :)

Comment: Messaging Queues like ActiveMq?

Comment: Simplest of all this, I have decided to run timer here in AIR app which will be calling my API and see if any operation is to be performed. Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

Air is Javascript, so you can use `XmlHTTPRequest` to make requests.

I have snipped this out of old production code, you might have to change a line here or there. 
Original code is here: [CommandProxy.js](https://github.com/kritzikratzi/CommandProxy/blob/master/CommandProxy.js)

```
/**
 * Make a call to a web service
 *
 * @param command The name of the command
 * @param parameters A map of parameters, e.g. { "file": "/myfile.pdf" }
 * @param (optional) callback, a function with one parameter, that will be given a json object when the result is ready.  
 */
function callWebservice( url, parameters, callback ){

    var async = (typeof (callback) == "function");

    if( !parameters )
        parameters = {};

    var paramString = ""; 
    for( var param in parameters ){
        paramString += encodeURI( param ) + "=" + encodeURI( parameters[param] ) + "&"; 
    }

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open( "POST", url, async ); 

    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-length", paramString.length);
    req.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    if( async ){
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){

            if( req.readystate == 4 && callback ) {
                if( req.status == 200 ){
                    callback( JSON.parse( req.responseText ) ); 
                }
                else{
                    callback( { "error" : req.responseText } ); 
                }
            }
        };
        req.send( paramString ); 
    }
    else{
        req.send( paramString ); 
        var ret = JSON.parse( req.responseText );

        return ret; 
    }
}
```

On a side note: I made a terrible experience with Adobe Air around five to six years ago. It was slow, error prone, badly documented, not very flexible and it feels "foreign" when run on a desktop. It seems not much has changed. I strongly suggest you google for alternatives, don't take this choice lightly!

Comment: AIR is not Javascript.  There is a way to build an AIR app using either HTML/Javascript or Actionscript, but IME the more typical way is Actionscript.

Comment: air allows the use of javascript. actionscript and javascript are mostly the same. the question doesn't mention actionscript (other than in the tags, not sure if that was changed after i answered). the code was used in production and works. so what's with the downvotes?

Comment: such an uneducated response.

Comment: @BotMaster care to provide some details?